# How do I allow a user to override a schedule?

Tags: modal-view

I'm designing an app which will allow a user to both **schedule playlists** at different times of the day **and override** that schedule to play a playlist. How do I communicate to the user that playing a playlist will override their current schedule and how do I allow them to switch back to schedule mode?

Comment: I have already implemented a gcal like calendar for scheduling playlists. However on another screen I have a list of playlists with a play button next to each and I think that people don't understand that playing that playlist would override the currently scheduled playlist.

Comment: What happens at the end of a playlist? Does it revert to the schedule automatically?

Comment: Not currently but I was thinking of offering choices upon press of the play button. Something like 1 hour, 3 hours, or indefinitely.

Comment: And does the app give any visual indication when it's playing something that was scheduled versus playing something that was not scheduled? I.e. could I tell the difference by glancing at the interface?

Comment: @MattObee not currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give them a choice when they try to start a playlist that will interfere with their schedule.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foAyZ6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I might be tempted to show which playlist(s) are affected, depending on how much information you want them to have.

As for "how do I allow them to switch back to schedule mode?", that's a little difficult to answer without seeing the rest of the interface. I do certainly think it's important that, whether the current playlist is scheduled or started manually, the user can tell the difference.

Answer (score 3):

I guess a playlist is a fixed-length event in a calendar-like something, even if more precise than calendar events usually are.

[image]

*done [using](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/demos/selectable.html) the fullcalendar jQuery plugin*

I don't see why you need modality here, it looks more like a [list-detail](http://designinginterfaces.com/firstedition/index.php?page=Two-Panel_Selector) issue to me.

Comment: Sorry my question had a typo in it. See my edit to my question.